# ERROR: Error installing mysql: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, windows-7-x64, mysql-5.1

I followed the "http://blog.mmediasys.com/2011/07/07/installing-mysql-on-windows-7-x64-and-using-ruby-with-it/" for setting the connection between Ruby on rails app and mysql server 5.1

So when I install the mysql gem with the following command:

```
gem install mysql --platform=ruby -- --with-mysql-dir=C:/mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32
```

So I'm getting the following error log:

> Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
>   Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
>   ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
>           ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
>    C:/Ruby187/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-mysql-dir=C:/mysql-connector-c
> ```
>
> -noinstall-6.0.2-win32
>   checking for main() in -llibmysql... no
>   *** extconf.rb failed ***
>   Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
>   necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
>   details.  You may need configuration options.
>
> Provided configuration options:
>           --with-opt-dir
>           --without-opt-dir
>           --with-opt-include
>           --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>           --with-opt-lib
>           --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>           --with-make-prog
>           --without-make-prog
>           --srcdir=.
>           --curdir
>           --ruby=C:/Ruby187/bin/ruby
>           --with-mysql-dir
>           --with-mysql-include
>           --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
>           --with-mysql-lib
>           --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
>           --with-libmysqllib
>           --without-libmysqllib
>
> Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.9.1
>    for inspection.
>   Results logged to C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.9.1/ext/mysql_api/ge
>   m_make.out

Extra Info:
Ruby version 1.8.7
Windows 7 64 bit
Mysql version 5.1

Answer (score 4):

1. Download the mysql/C connector Zip file.
2. UnZip that to the specific folder say `C: drive`.
3. Copy the `libmySQL.dll from mysql/C` connector Zip file.
4. try this command `gem install mysql --platform=ruby` -- --with-`mysql-lib=C:\mysql-C-connector\lib` --with-`mysql-include=c:\mysql-C-connector\include`

Comment: when ur ans is text no need to include in html,boby tags .No need to use tags

Answer (score 2):

Please install Devkit first
https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/development-kit
http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

Follow instructions from github repo and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier for you to install rails with the [railsinstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/).